# Writing to two Redis servers

Tags: redis, replication, queueing

I am looking for a way to send Redis writes *from one particular client* to two Redis servers running on different hosts.

This isn't quite replication,  if writes come in from any other client I do not want those to be replicated.   e.g. writes from producers go to redis1 & redis2.   writes from consumer1 & consumer2 (really, deletes) should only modify redis1 & redis2, respectively

```
              /----> redis1 <-- consumer1
producer --->
              \----> redis2 <-- consumer2
```

Thanks!

Comment: what stops you from explicitly writing to two redis instances from your producer?

Comment: thanks.    someone else owns the piece of code that connects to redis and sends commands to it -- hasn't had the bandwidth to do what you describe else it's a good idea.   i'm  looking for a proxy of sorts that i could just change configuration to point at (that's less in-depth than actually getting the java code and building it, etc)

Comment: if you cannot change the code at all, then I cannot think of any solution other than writing a redis mock service that mimics redis and sends commands to a real instance.

Comment: Use the "Answer your question" button so I can select your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the code at all, then I cannot think of any solution other than writing a service that mimics Redis and sends commands to real instances.

This project can be useful: https://github.com/causes/mock_redis